# Prove smooth functions vanishing at infinity belong to Schwartz space

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, schwartz-space

I believe the definition of $C^{\infty}_0(\mathbb R^n)$ is
$$\{f(x):\forall\alpha\in\mathbb N^n,D^{\alpha}f(x)\in C_0 \cap C^{\infty}\}$$
note that $\alpha$ is a multi-index with nonnegative integer coordinates. I want to prove these functions are in Schwartz space $\mathcal S$
$$\mathcal S:=\{f(x)\in C^\infty:\sup_{x\in\mathbb R^n}|x^{\alpha}D^{\beta}f(x)|\lt\infty \}$$
It is clear from the definition that $D^\beta f(x)\in C_0^\infty$ if $f(x)\in C_0^\infty$ thus $\sup_{x\in\mathbb R^n}|D^\beta f(x)|<\infty$. How do I show that for any $\alpha\in \mathbb N^n$, $\sup_{x\in \mathbb R^n} |x^\alpha f(x)|\lt \infty$? In the case I wrongly stated some definitions, do correct me.

Comment: Are you sure it's $C_0$ and not $C_c$?

Comment: @podiki in my lecture handouts it is.

Comment: What about $f(x)= \frac{1}{1+x^2}$?

Comment: @podiki maybe that's a typo in my lecture notes, so the inverse inclusion is correct then, $\mathcal S \subset C_0^\infty$. Also if my definition of $C_0^\infty$ correct?

Comment: Yes, that should be easier to prove. And $C_c^\infty\subset\mathcal{S}$.